# cat: can't open '/tmp/drive/P0.RAW': No such file or directory

Tags: shell, embedded-linux

The script pasted below causes the following error:

> cat: can't open '/tmp/drive/P0.RAW': No such file or directory

It looks like the script does not properly evaluate `$N` for the filename.
How `$N` be made to evaluate so the file name is something like P01L.RAW, P02L.RAW, etc.?

```
N=1
until [ $N -ge 10 ]; do
    cat bmpheader.bmp /tmp/drive/P0$NL.RAW > ./P0$NL.bmp
    ./quality_metric_test ./P0$NL.bmp
    N=$((N + 1))
done
```

Comment: Tried putting parens and various types of quotes around `$N` without any success

Comment: And yes: there is a /tmp/drive/P01L.RAW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that bash interprets all uppercase characters as part of the variable by default, so it's looking for `$NL` instead of just `$N`. This is why it returns just `P0.RAW`, as `$NL` is an unexisting variable. You can easily avoid that by a minor syntax adjustment, call the variable with curly brackets (`{` and `}`) around it. Replace this:

```
cat bmpheader.bmp /tmp/drive/P0$NL.RAW > ./P0$NL.bmp
./quality_metric_test ./P0$NL.bmp
```

With this:

```
cat bmpheader.bmp /tmp/drive/P0${N}L.RAW > ./P0${N}L.bmp
./quality_metric_test ./P0${N}L.bmp
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks a million. I kind of thought it was something like that so I tried various things to separate the N without success. I suppose it might be best to use lower case for variables going forward. Should a lower case 'n' or 'i' have also worked?